# Unpacking rar file gives empty folder

Tags: installation

I have a kinda weird problem. I have Ubuntu 13.04 x86-64 installed with everything default and updated. I have installed unrar-free to unpack a rar file containing files. When opening the file with Archive Manager all the files are inside the rarfile. But when I extract them to a new folder with the folder remains empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What options did you select for extracting the files? There are options to only extract the selected item without recursion. I think you may have hit that option. Could you please include a screenshot of the extract dialogue in your question?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who is still having some doubts about this topic, I found the info on how to solve it from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1033170). This is what I worked for me:

I have Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

1. I checked what unrar version I had installed.

   `$ dpkg --list | grep unrar`

   I found out that I had installed unrar-free
2. I uninstall **unrar-free** and install **unrar**

   `$ sudo apt-get remove unrar-free -y && sudo apt-get install unrar -y`